# UWP ListView selected item highlight disappears if ItemContainerStyle is set

Tags: xaml, listview, uwp

I am using a `ListView` to display a list of items. But when I set the font of the items using `ItemContainerStyle` and now an item is selected, the `ListView` highlight (blue line on the left) is no longer visible. On this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5NWm.png) here is a comparison. The problem has come with the installation of the [`Microsoft.UI.Xaml` package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui2/getting-started), because here the design of `ListView` has been changed. Is there any way to fix this without having to remove `ItemContainerStyle` or the `Microsoft.UI.Xaml` package?

MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
      
      <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <ListViewItem Content="ABCD"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="abcd"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="1234"/>
      </ListView>

      <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <ListViewItem Content="ABCD"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="abcd"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="1234"/>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
          <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"></Setter>
          </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
      </ListView>
      
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

App.xaml

```
<Application
    x:Class="App1.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1">
    <Application.Resources>
      <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: After testing the code in Windows 10 and Windows 11 in a blank UWP application, I have to say that the code you are sharing is not enough to reproduce the behavior you got. Could you please reproduce this in a blank UWP app and share the code that could reproduce this issue?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I created a new Blank App and pasted all the code into my question.

Comment: If you just want to change properties like `FontSize` or `Background` for one of the items, you could directly set it.  That's a workaround for such a scenario because these properties are built-in properties that you could directly modify without giving a style.

Comment: Yes I know that, but in my main application the list is initially empty and the items are then inserted there programmatically according to the user's settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is that when you set a new `ItemContainerStyle` for the listview, it overrides the default item style that is used from the WinUI library.

The solution to this is that you need to give the item a style based on the style that the item is currently using. I find the default style of the `ListViewItem` in WinUI GitHub: [ListViewItem_themeresources](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/main/dev/CommonStyles/ListViewItem_themeresources.xaml). So you just need to create a style that is based on the `DefaultListViewItemStyle`.

You will need to change a little bit of your code like this:

```
 <ListView>
        <ListViewItem Content="ABCD"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="abcd"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="1234" />
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultListViewItemStyle}">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="25"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
```